# redirect any non-existent requests (files\folders) to root domain page 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to redirect any non-existent requests (files\folders\subfolders) to the root domain.com. Currently it's showing:

Not Found

The requested URL /awddawd was not found on this server.
Apache/x.x.x.x.x (Debian) Server at domain.com Port 80

Comment: Ok, fine with us, go for it! (or do you have a question here?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use basic rewriting as offered by Apaches mod_rewrite module:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule - / [L,R=301]
```

Best is to place such rules right into the (virtual) host configuration between basic host definitions and directory/location tags.

An alternative is to use .htaccess style files in the document file hierarchy, but that is much more error prone, harder to debug and really slows the server down. So only do this if you have no access to the server configuration. Such files must be readable by the http server process and obviously support for such files must be enabled in the server configuration. A .htaccess style file holding general rules like this probably is best placed right inside the top level directory of the (virtual) hosts `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: Does this need to be put in a .htaccess file in the root directory? And if so what privledge does it need to be cdmod'd as?

Comment: Sorry, I added some basic info to the answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: I was able to enable the Apache mod_rewrite module. Where do I place this in the /etc/apache2 folder?

Comment: Locate the place where the host is configured: as a _virtual host_ or as _the host_, this depends on your setup. Such section starts with stuff like `ServerAdmin ...` and `ServerName ...` directives, further down you find definitions about a `DirectoryRoot ...` and one or more `<Directory ...>...</Directory>` definitions. Just put the lines intbetween, as a block.Try a `rcapache2 configtest` (openSUSE example) to test the syntax or right away restart the apache server (`rcapache2 graceful` or `/etc/init.d/apache2 graceful`). It will complain in the error log if something is wrong.