# 301 redirect wordpress to html

Tags: html, wordpress, redirect

I hope someone can help me - I've searched for an answer to this but can't find it, apologies if it has been answered before.

I have a customer who wants to switch from an existing domain with website built on Wordpress, to a new domain with website built in HTML, and I'm struggling to work out how to redirect the site properly in the htaccess file.

I know that for the inner pages I can use:

```
Redirect 301 /existing-wordpress-page http://www.newsite.com/new-page.html
Redirect 301 /another-wordpress-page http://www.newsite.com/another-page.html
```

But how would you also redirect the wordpress home page to the new index.html page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [redirect any non-existent requests (files\folders) to root domain page 404](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162667/redirect-any-non-existent-requests-files-folders-to-root-domain-page-404)